# How to load OSM highway values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, quickosm

I want to extract the rest areas along highways using  quick OSM in QGIS. But I'm facing an issue that there is no value for rest_area. Does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: Well, which tags are you working with?

Comment: @Erik: I guess that's the question the OP has: "there is no value for rest_area". I think OP's question is not really if someone else has this problem, but rather how to identify rest areas.

Comment: Ah, I see... in that case one could start out with (public) toilets, since a lot of rest areas have those. Maybe also look for banks?

Comment: I was looking into the OSM map features and it mentions there is a specific value for rest_area with Highway key. I also realized I do not have most of the values on this page: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_features
do you have any thoughts about the map features?
Sorry it is my first time using QGIS and OSM 
Thanks @Erik

Comment: Just did a test-run with `highway=rest_area` for Northern Germany and got about 350 returns through all geometry types. So probably for your area of interest the tag wasn't used?

Comment: It might be the case

Comment: @Erik: `highway=services` is used in (northern) Germany as well, see e.g.: https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/314084532

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an OSM-Tag `highway=services` (see [this example](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/92230075)), however, it is not always used (see [this example](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/322652113)). So this is a limitation of OSM data: what is missing on the map (what is not tagged in the OSM database) can't be found: OSM data is incomplete.

The second example shows this clearly: it is not tagged as such in OSM, even thought it exists since 1972 (!) and is one of the most prominent resting areas in Switzerland, having even an [own Wikipedia-entry](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autobahnrastst%C3%A4tte_W%C3%BCrenlos) and an [own website](https://www.shopping-raststaette.ch/). You could add it yourself to OSM. For many countries, there are websites with lists of resting areas - however, this is not as handy as downloading it form OSM.

What you can do: download highways, create a buffer around it of say 40 or 100 meters and look for parking spaces `amenity=parking` within this buffer.